# Django - is model metadata inherited?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a hierarchy of classes in my `models.py`.  I would like all of the actual tables I define to have the same `unique_together` constraint.  So I would like to put this in the `Meta` class of the base class from which they all inherit.  Of course this base class also needs to specify `abstract = True` in it's `Meta` class, and I don't want the inheriting classes to be abstract.

Do I have to specify the same `unique_together` constraint multiple times, once for each non-abstract class that inherits from the abstract base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance)

> When an abstract base class is created, Django makes any Meta inner class you declared in the base class available as an attribute. If a child class does not declare its own Meta class, it will inherit the parent’s Meta. If the child wants to extend the parent’s Meta class, it can subclass it.

and also:

> Django does make one adjustment to the Meta class of an abstract base class: before installing the Meta attribute, it sets abstract=False. This means that children of abstract base classes don’t automatically become abstract classes themselves. Of course, you can make an abstract base class that inherits from another abstract base class. You just need to remember to explicitly set abstract=True each time.

Comment: hmm, I guess I could have RTFM'd, but this was faster, I think.